# Can I switch off Oracle JDBC auto commit when closing a connection?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, transactions

As we know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825353/partial-commit-when-connection-close-in-oracle-with-hibernate-jpa), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233720/jdbc-and-oracle-conn-commit-and-conn-setautocommit-not-working-properly) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218350/does-java-connection-close-rollback) for a start, calling close on a JDBC connection to Oracle results in a commit although this may not be the case for other JDBC drivers.

I can do a rollback before closing specifically for Oracle, but I was curious whether anybody knows if I can switch this off when opening the connection in a similar way to switching off the auto commit? Thank you.

Comment: As the third question/answer you linked states, you should always perform a commit or rollback prior to closing the connection if auto commit is set to false, otherwise the behavior is implementation dependent.

Comment: I understand that and have done that - thank you (but it wasn't the question :) ).

Comment: What's the question then? Switch _what_ off? Every transaction must either be committed or rolled back, and in this scenario it is driver-dependent what happens if you don't specifically do one or the other.

Comment: Well in my case it should be rolled back. I understand what you mean, thank you (and sorry if it was a cheeky comment to your comment). The question is the headline - I don't see what is wrong about asking that.

Comment: Well, your title implies that you are using the connection with auto-commit on, but you are not. No, you cannot turn off the _behavior_ of some drivers to commit on close (when auto-commit is off), since this behavior is not defined. You need to do a rollback yourself to be safe.

Comment: OK, yes, that could be misunderstood - sorry. Well the behaviour of a particular driver might be defined in the driver, but anyway. I think your first comment and your comment just above now answer the question fully, so if I could mark them as answers.. Oh well, you have points enough!

Answer (score 0):

You could try subclassing the Connection class and set autoCommit = false in the constructor for example

Comment: Already did that, thanks, but it will still commit on calling close.